# What is the Trigger for Biota Attacks in Alien Legacy?

Tags: alien-legacy

In the DOS game Alien Legacy the native biota eventually attack the player on two planets.  There seems to be a trigger, number of triggers, or a random chance.  Does anyone know for sure and what the trigger might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [forum](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?p=211635) thread, where someone answered that:

> The Biota attack is triggered when you exceed 29 habitats anywhere in the system. If you have less than 30 the attacks will begin on turn 2,000.

Comment: I confirm the turn 2,000 as maximum turn before the biota attacks start. Tried it with 29 habitats maximum.